# django urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch error happens when I want to use reverse function in unittests?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, namespaces, pycharm

I recently started developing an application with django and [this](https://github.com/masouduut94/django_rest_api_TDD) is the link to whole project.

this is the project structure:

```
config/
    env/
        .env files
    requirements/
        __init__.py
        ...
    settings/
        __init__.py
        base.py
        local.py
    __init__.py
    urls.py
    views.py
    wsgi.py
projects/
    api/
        town/
            apps.py
            urls.py
            views.py
        ...
    core/
        models/
            town.py
        serializers/
            town_serializer.py
        ...
tests/
    test_town.py
manage.py
```

this is the file `project/api/town.urls.py` :

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'town'

urlpatterns = [
    path('town/', views.CreateTownView.as_view(), name='town-list'),
    path('town/<int:pk>/', views.TownViewSet.as_view(), name='town-detail')
]
```

And the file for `config/settings/urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
# from .views import views

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
# path('', views.index)
path('api/', include('project.api.city.urls', namespace='city')),
path('api/', include('project.api.town.urls', namespace='town'))
```

]

API works just fine when I use this link to check out: `localhost:8000/api/town` but when I am trying to run the unit tests in pycharm, unfortunately some error occurs.  This is some part of test module which error happens in DETAIL_TOWN_URL = reverse('town:town-detail') :

```
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.test import TestCase
from project.core.models.town import Town
from django.urls import reverse

from rest_framework.test import APIClient
from rest_framework import status

import unittest

CREATE_TOWN_URL = reverse('town:town-list')
DETAIL_TOWN_URL = reverse('town:town-detail')
```

this is the error:

```
raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'town-detail' with no arguments not found.
```

Obviously reverse cant find the term `town-detail`, but as you can see in `project/api/town.urls.py` I had defined `town-detail` and also `town` app urls in project main urls as namespace `town`.

When I comment the `DETAIL_TOWN_URL`, I realize that tests with `CREATE_TOWN_URL` will pass but when `DETAIL_TOWN_URL` is defined and not commented, the error occurs.

So why this error happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: habe a look at reverse_lazy: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Town detail required int argument in url.

Try to use kwargs

reverse('town-detail', kwargs={'pk': 1})

Or args
reverse('town-detail', args=[1]))

There is link to documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/

Comment: I just found out and returned to put an answer but I saw your reply. Anyway thanks a million for the time you put on it